# Android ACTION_VIEW No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android

Trying to handle a http with a textview

```
              Pattern httpMatcher = Pattern.compile("https?://.*"); 
              String httpViewURL = "myhttp";
              Linkify.addLinks(label, httpMatcher, httpViewURL);
```

manifest file:

```
    <activity android:exported="false"
        android:name="*****.URLClickedActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
            <data android:scheme="myhttp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Anyway I get this:

**No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=**  (has extras) }*

Comment: put your full log cat here

Comment: Why are you using ``myhttp`` scheme? Should it be ``myhttp://`` or something similar?

Comment: you have right, thanks, that was the solution @harism

Comment: @harism You should post your comment as an answer to officially resolve this question (and get your reputation points).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scheme

```
String httpViewURL = "myhttp";
```

should read

```
String httpViewURL = "myhttp://";
```